Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IHostItemFactoryNoMAF'

Exception Message: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IHostItemFactoryNoMAF'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{**}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
Exception Source: Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Implementation
Stacktrace:
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.GetVstoObject(_Workbook workbook, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, UInt32 officeVersion)
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorksheetImpl.GetVstoObject(IVstoObjectProvider objectProvider, _Worksheet worksheet, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, UInt32 officeVersion)
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObjectImpl.GetVstoObject(IVstoObjectProvider objectProvider, ListObject listObject)

The exception is getting generated from this code:
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject ls = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(listObject);

I'm using .NET 4.8.
Code:
public static void FormatComponent() 
{ 
    Dictionary<string, ListObject> listObjects = ExcelHelper.GetListObjects();
    ListObject listObject = null;

    listObjects.TryGetValue(matrix.MatrixName, out listObject);

    if (listObject != null)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject ls = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(listObject);

        if (ls != null)
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}

public static Dictionary<string, ListObject> GetListObjects() 
{ 
    Sheets sheets = Globals.Ribbons.Rainier.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets; var listObjects = new Dictionary<string, ListObject>();

    foreach (Worksheet sheet in sheets)
    {
        ListObjects ls = sheet.ListObjects;
    
        if (ls != null && ls.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListObject listObj in ls)
            {
                listObjects.Add(listObj.Name, listObj);
            }
        }
    }

    return listObjects;
}

I tried the following, but the issue did not get resolved:

Deleted the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT - TypeLib - {00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} - 1.9

Quick repair - Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise - en-us


